# Count all row on data grid view with out duplicate in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to count all row on `DataGridView` with out duplicate in VB.NET?

If rows are

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
BB
```

Then count should be 4.

Comment: Do you mean your DataGridView has just one Column? Or each row has (5?) Columns which may all have identical values?

Comment: I have multiple colums

Comment: Then you have to update your data sample to better explain the actual context. Post an image of your DataGridView if you think it can better describe its structure.

Comment: Also, you should specify what is the DataSource, if any, of the DataGridView. Possibly showing how it is filled (showing these details is somewhat mandatory), since the possible solutions may depend on how these actions are performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have craeted sampe Widnows Forms application with `DataGridView` called `DataGridview1`.

Then I created method to count distinct rows in `DataGridview1`, also I added helper method to check whether two `DataGridViewRow`s are equal or not, here it is (necessary comments in code):

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Sample data
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "col1")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "col2")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col3", "col3")
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, 3, 3)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(2, 2, 3)
    End Sub
    Private Function CountDistinctRows() As Integer
        Dim distinctRows As Integer = 0
        Dim alreadyCountedRows = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim isRowAlreadyCounted As Boolean
            For Each r As DataGridViewRow In alreadyCountedRows
                isRowAlreadyCounted = AreRowsEqual(row, r)
                If isRowAlreadyCounted Then Exit For
            Next
            ' If we have row, which wasn't already counted, we have to add it
            ' to collection of added rows and increment the counter of distinct rows
            If Not isRowAlreadyCounted Then
                alreadyCountedRows.Add(row)
                distinctRows = distinctRows + 1
            End If
        Next
        Return distinctRows
    End Function

    Private Function AreRowsEqual(row1 As DataGridViewRow, row2 As DataGridViewRow)
        ' Sanity check
        If row1.Cells.Count <> row2.Cells.Count Then Throw New ArgumentException("Rows are of different size!")
        For i = 0 To row1.Cells.Count - 1
            If row1.Cells(i).Value <> row2.Cells(i).Value Then Return False
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: How to count only in one column cell(0)

Comment: @GPlay Just change in method `AreRowsEqual` checking only first cell in row: `If row1.Cells(0).Value <> row2.Cells(0).Value Then Return False Else Return True` and get rid of `For` loop.

Comment: How to count where value is equal to textbox.text before distinctrows increments